# Facing this Error : myisamchk: error: File '/var/lib/mysql/bugs/*.MYI' doesn't exist on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, myisam

Recently i tried to run [myisamchk](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html) Maintenance Utility program with some tables under myisam storage engine and i follow  this [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-repair-corrupted-mysql-tables-using-myisamchk/) and got errors that i was unable to figure out.

on terminal i type this command and got this error:

```
 sudo myisamchk  /var/lib/mysql/bugs/*.MYI >> /home/mysqlTestingFiles/myisamchk_log.txt
 myisamchk: error: File '/var/lib/mysql/bugs/*.MYI' doesn't exist
```

I also manually looked for this */var/lib/mysql/**bugs*** folders But did not find it there!
is this **bugs** folder should be inside that location by default?
so, how can i resolve this problem?
let me know for further information.Thanks.

After getting useful comments, i try this code and it worked for **a specific table** `sudo myisamchk /var/lib/mysql/test_database/student.MYI >> /home/mysqlTestingFiles/myisamchk_log.txt` 
But I want to check all the .MYI files with this code and got error:

```
sudo myisamchk /var/lib/mysql/test_database/*.MYI >> /home/mysqlTestingFiles/myisamchk_log.txt 
myisamchk: error: File '/var/lib/mysql/test_database/*.MYI doesn't exist
```

Why its not working for all .MYI files stored in Database.Please reply.Thanks

Comment: you should probably replace `bugs` with the name of the database you want to fix. check your `/var/lib/mysql/` for existing directories (i.e. databases).

Comment: so, are you saying that **bugs** folder is not any built-in folder that come with mysql.Instead its **just a database name**.

Comment: that is exactly what i am saying.

Comment: After getting useful comments, i try this code and it worked for **a specific table** `sudo myisamchk /var/lib/mysql/test_database/student.MYI >> /home/mysqlTestingFiles/myisamchk_log.txt` 
But I want to check all the .MYI files with this code and got error:
 

    `sudo myisamchk /var/lib/mysql/test_database/*.MYI >> /home/mysqlTestingFiles/myisamchk_log.txt 
  myisamchk: error: File '/var/lib/mysql/test_database/*.MYI doesn't exist `

Why its not working for all .MYI files stored in Database.Please reply.Thanks

Comment: MyISAM and its myisamchk are ancient history; you should move to InnoDB.

Comment: Thanks  for this  information.

Comment: That's not helpful, MyISAM tables still have their place and are widely used.  This may be something that's just changed in the version you have?  I have been doing this for years
`time find . -name "*.MYI" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} myisamchk --key_buffer_size=2G --sort_buffer_size=2G -farSU {}`

On at least 30 different DB servers for the last 10 years.  However now on a recent installed server, this command doesn't work, and gives that same myisam error.  Why?

I can do myisamchk table, but not myisamchk table.MYI  this is a change to behaviour.